# React Native Count One Up Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-native

I'm new to React / React Native and I'm trying to make a function that will go from 0 to 100 and display it in a graphic gauge. Simulating a Speedometer that will go from 0 to 100 MPH. So here is my *onPress* function that will count one if its pressed:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Text,
    View,
} from 'react-native';
import Speedometer from 'react-native-speedometer-chart';

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { count: 0 }
    }

onPress = () => {
    this.setState({
        count: this.state.count+1
    })
}
```

Then, I added a while statement that if *count* is less than 100 it will keep going one up. The problem is that it doesn't count.

```
onPress = () => {
    while(this.state.count < 100) {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count+1
        })
    }
}
```

Can someone help with this. Here is the full code that I have:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Text,
    View,
} from 'react-native';
import Speedometer from 'react-native-speedometer-chart';

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { count: 0 }
    }

    onPress = () => {
        while(this.state.count <= 100) {
            this.setState({
                count: this.state.count+1
            })
        }
    }

    clear = () => {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count = 0
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.titleText}> AlphaDyne New Run Screen</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.onPress}>
                    <Text> Start Run </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={[styles.countContainer]}>
                    <Speedometer
                        value={this.state.count !== 0 ? this.state.count: 0}
                        totalValue={100}
                        size={250}
                        outerColor="#d3d3d3"
                        internalColor="#ff0000"
                        showText
                        text="MPH"
                        textStyle={{ color: '#ff0000' }}
                        showLabels
                        labelStyle={{ color: '#FF00FF' }}
                    />
                    <Text style={styles.countText}>{this.state.count !== 0 ? this.state.count: 0} MPH</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.space}></Text>
                    <Speedometer
                        value={this.state.count !== 0 ? this.state.count: 0}
                        totalValue={100}
                        size={250}
                        showIndicator
                        showLabels
                        labelStyle={{ color: '#FF00FF' }}
                    />
                    <Text style={styles.countText}>{this.state.count !== 0 ? this.state.count: 0} MPH</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.spacer}></Text>
                    <Text style={styles.spacer}></Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.clear}>
                        <Text> Clear </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        paddingHorizontal: 10
    },
    button: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
        padding: 10
    },
    countContainer: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: 10,
        marginTop: 20
    },
    countText: {
        color: '#FF00FF',
        fontSize: 20,
        marginTop: 10
    },
    titleText: {
        fontSize: 30,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginBottom: 20
    },
    space: {
        marginTop: 20
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't count"?

Comment: It's supposed to start going from 0 to 1, 2, 3, 4... until 100. But it stays in zero when I press it.

Comment: did you do any debugging? If so can you add it into your question? Like do you know if the state is incrementing? Or is it a problem with the Speedometer component?

Comment: I did. I thinks there's a problem with updating the state because if I remove the while and just leave the setState it works. But only go one up if I press it. I want to press it once and the count go from 0 to 100 and every time it changes it update the state.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call functional setState to overcome asynchronicity problems with your solution:

```js
onPress = () => {
  while(this.state.count <= 100) {
    this.setState(previousState => ({ ...previousState, count: previousState.count + 1 }));
  }
}
```

for reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-is-the-difference-between-passing-an-object-or-a-function-in-setstate

Comment: So I tried this but it still doesn't change or update the state. Check it out here: https://snack.expo.io/@santiago0713/nervous-candies

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? Have you tried this `react-native-speedometer`. https://reactjsexample.com/a-customizable-speedometer-implementation-in-react-native/

Comment: I want a function that will take state "count" from 0 to 100 and update the Gauge every time it changes. Like simulation a car going from 0 to 100 MPH, that you can see the Gauges going up.